# Event Primefaces overlay menu, how to handle close menu action?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 3.2, and I'm looking for a way to handle closing action of a overlay menu.

```
<pf:commandButton id="actions" type="button" onclick="unbindResize(this); ${cc.attrs.onClickButton}"/>
<pf:menu id="menu" position="dynamic" trigger="actions" my="left top" at="left bottom">
    <pf:menuitem value="" action="" oncomplete="" update=""/> // all values filled and has been removed.
</pf:menu>
```

I can easily handle the open action with the onclick attribute of the commandButton, but what about the menu closure ? Because you can close the menu clicking anywhere in the window...

Is there a way to handle the action "close the menu" ?

Comment: I can detect the menu is opening because of the click on the commandButton. But how is it possible to detect the menu is going to close ?

Comment: So you want to be able to call some javascript client side when the menu is closed (on the close event)?

Comment: That's correct :) I implemented an horrible hack for moment (basically, a body.onclick outside the menu...), maybe there is better than this...